# create span after li a in categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

in my categories widget items displaying below the format in wordpress.

```
<ul>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Construction</a>(2)</li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="#">uncategorized</a> (1)</li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="">Workers</a> (1)</li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-9"><a href="">Workplace</a> (1)</li>
</ul>
```

I want to display the categories list in below the format. anyone help me.

```
<ul>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Construction</a>(2)<span class="demo"></span></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="#">uncategorized</a> (1)<span class="demo"></span>/li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="">Workers</a> (1)<span class="demo"></span></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-9"><a href="">Workplace</a> (1)<span class="demo"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

This my code to generate list items. category.php file in theme file.

```
function get_the_category_list( $separator = '', $parents='', $post_id = false ) {
global $wp_rewrite;
if ( ! is_object_in_taxonomy( get_post_type( $post_id ), 'category' ) ) {
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
    return apply_filters( 'the_category', '', $separator, $parents );
}

$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
if ( empty( $categories ) ) {
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
    return apply_filters( 'the_category', __( 'Uncategorized' ), $separator, $parents );
}

$rel = ( is_object( $wp_rewrite ) && $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) ? 'rel="category tag"' : 'rel="category"';

$thelist = '';
if ( '' == $separator ) {
    $thelist .= '<ul class="post-categories">';
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $thelist .= "\n\t<li>";
        switch ( strtolower( $parents ) ) {
            case 'multiple':
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, true, $separator );
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
                break;
            case 'single':
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '"  ' . $rel . '>';
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, false, $separator );
                $thelist .= $category->name.'</a></li>';
                break;
            case '':
            default:
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    $thelist .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( 0 < $i )
            $thelist .= $separator;
        switch ( strtolower( $parents ) ) {
            case 'multiple':
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, true, $separator );
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
                break;
            case 'single':
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>';
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, false, $separator );
                $thelist .= "$category->name</a>";
                break;
            case '':
            default:
                $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
        }
        ++$i;
    }
}

/**
 * Filter the category or list of categories.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @param array  $thelist   List of categories for the current post.
 * @param string $separator Separator used between the categories.
 * @param string $parents   How to display the category parents. Accepts 'multiple',
 *                          'single', or empty.
 */
return apply_filters( 'the_category', $thelist, $separator, $parents );
}
```

Comment: Where's your PHP code for generating this html? That would help...

Comment: that is wordpress default widget

Comment: Ok...so please show the PHP code that's generating it.

Comment: My code displaying above. please check my code. thanks

Comment: Its not working Mr.mevius.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change lines that look like this:

```
$thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
```

By adding your `<span>`s to them. Something like:

```
$thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a><span class="demo"></span></li>';
```